# Warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data when compiling sorting algorithms

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm a student new to C++, and I'm encountering an error and unsure of how to approach or correct this.

I'm working on implementing sorts for random, reverse-sorted, and sorted number files. These are all in .txt form and I can successfully read them in. Unfortunately, when I run my sorts, I can only get past the random-generated sorts; both reverse and sorted files fail.

I am calling my functions as such from my header files:

```
quickSort(array, 0, vector.size() - 1);
```

And the actual function itself takes these parameters as input:

```
void quickSort(int array[], int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
if (startIndex < endIndex)
    {
    int partitionIndex = partition(array, startIndex, endIndex);
    quickSort(array, startIndex, partitionIndex - 1);
    quickSort(array, partitionIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }
}
```

In order to read the numbers from the file in, I'm reading them in to a vector, then copying the vector into an array, and then sorting that array. Some of the files have huge amounts of numbers in them, up to a million.

I've read about size_t and int and how a conversion to int from size_t may result in a loss of data, but unsure of where or how that applies in my code. Also, this error only happens during runtime, but compiles perfectly fine.

Comment: I notice that your `quickSort` never actually performs any sorting. It never acts upon `array`.

Comment: `vector.size()` returns a `std::size_t`, but `quickSort` takes `int`s for the start/end indices.  The warning is telling you that if the vector's size is larger than can be represented by an `int`, your function will break.

Comment: I'm more curious what possible relationship `vector` and `array` have in this code.

Comment: I'm guessing horrendous naming, but I'm also surprised you can name an object after a type. I'm also guessing the sorting is done in `partition()`. Or maybe not. This question doesn't provide an [mre].

Comment: I'm a real novice with C++, I couldn't figure out a way to read numbers in to an array and sort it, so what I did was read in to a vector, copy the entire vector to an array, and then use the array to run the sorts.

I didn't know that vector.size() returns a std::size_t, so that's super helpful! Thank you very much! I think I'm on my way to a solution!

Comment: _"copy the entire vector to an array, and then use the array to run the sorts"_ - Don't. Using a `std::vector` was the right call, but there's no need to copy the data into an array.  Just do: `quickSort(vector.data(), 0, vector.size() - 1);`

Comment: `Also, this error only happens during runtime, but compiles perfectly fine.` - are you sure about that? The caption certainly looks like a compile-time error. Anyway, you have (at least) two options: either cast the `vector.size()` expression to `int`: `quickSort(array, 0, (int)(vector.size() - 1));` - or else change the start and end indices to use `size_t` instead of `int`. The former means that your code only works for array sizes up to `int` size, but that's way more than a million anyway.